# How to write withcolumn as reusable code in scala

Tags: dataframe, scala, function, apache-spark, reusability

Below is my code how can I write optimal code for withcolumn as a reusable code since the conditions are quite similar and I might use the withcolumn in other dataframes as well.

```
    val sample = df1.alias("a").join(df2.alias("b")
      ,Seq("ReportingSetID","ProductLine","PlanID","ReportType","NumeratorID","MemberID","ServDate"))
      .withColumn("IsNumeratorSupplemental",
        when (col("a.IsNumerator")===1 && col("b.IsNumerator")===0,1).otherwise(0))
      .withColumn("IsExclusionSupplemental",
        when (col("a.IsExclusion")===1 && col("b.IsExclusion")===0,1).otherwise(0))
      .withColumn("IsSubExclusionSupplemental",
        when (col("a.IsSubExclusion")===1 && col("b.IsSubExclusion")===0,1).otherwise(0))
      .withColumn("IsRequiredExclusionSupplemental",
        when (col("a.IsRequiredExclusion")===1 && col("b.IsRequiredExclusion")===0,1).otherwise(0))
      .filter(!col("b.MeasureID").isin("44","70"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write a simple method that takes a `DataFrame` and adds the column like this:

```scala
def withSupplemental(columnName : String)(df: DataFrame) = {
    df.withColumn(s"${columnName}Supplemental",
        when (col(s"a.$columnName")===1 && col(s"b.$columnName")===0,1).otherwise(0))
}
```

Optionally, this could also become an *extension method* if you feel the need for it.